# Keep detail rows in master detail it is not working well

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have the following code for my grid and set the property keepDetailRows in order that my detail component never rerenders again, if I expand and collapse any row slowly it works wells, the component doesn't rerender, but in case I do it fast and many times it eventually rerenders, this is a huge problem for me because the state inside the component get lost. I also tried having the state of the detail inside its parente and pass it through "detailCellRendererParams",  the problem is that when I update that state in the detail nothing happens.

```
        <SimpleGrid
      styleDiv={{
        height: '60vh',
        minHeight: '500px'
      }}
      quickFilterText={filterValue}
      defaultColDef={{
        minWidth: 100,
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true
      }}
      columnDefs={DATA_EXTRACTION_COLUMNS}
      groupDisplayType={'singleColumn'}
      autoGroupColumnDef={COLUMN_GROUP_DEF}
      masterDetail={true}
      detailCellRenderer={'myDetailCellRenderer'}
      detailCellRendererParams={{
        queryPlansAndFields,
        tenantId,
        dispatchQueryPlansAndFields,
        refreshStrategy: 'nothing'
      }}
      frameworkComponents={{
        myDetailCellRenderer: DataExtractionQueryFields
      }}
      animateRows={true}
      detailRowHeight={'28'}
      detailRowAutoHeight={true}
      keepDetailRows
      onSelectionChanged={onSelectionChanged}
      groupSelectsChildren={true}
      suppressRowClickSelection
      multiSelect
      setApi={onGridReady}
    />
```

Comment: state gets lost means you are probably hiding and showing you child component based on value from ur parent like -> { someValue && <ChildComponent/> } , when ever someValue goes falsy component is unmounted and state is reset, i dont know your setup but maybe can you can move the hideandshow part inside your child ?

Comment: I don't have control over that state,  I'm using an aggrid component https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/master-detail/ and unfortunately  that library doesn't follow react declarative programing so it doesn't update the props of the children